# Which are the folders to be included from the zip file for Alloy UI if I only want the Form Builder in my application

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3, alloy-ui

I am using Alloy UI  Form Builder in an application for which I have included all the files that come under the "Build" folder in the downloaded zip file for Alloy UI. I am not sure if all these folders are necessary to be included since I want only the Form Builder part.Can anyone help me so that I can keep only the required files and remove the rest

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a Java question as it looks to involve Javascript only and not Java. Are you sure about your use of the [tag:java] tag? Please correct me if I'm wrong, but note that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help.

Answer (score 0):

AlloyUI is built on top of YUI, which uses a module system for loading the necessary files for the part of the code you need to use. The simplest and most recommended way of using it is the one specified in AlloyUI's [site](http://alloyui.com/), which is just to add the main file from the cdn and specify what module you want to use, for example: `YUI().use('aui-form-builder)`. Check out the [site](http://alloyui.com/) for more details.

Of course you can instead specify each file you want to load on your html directly, but to do this you need to first figure out what all the dependencies for the module you want are (which can be complicated), and in the end you'll have a lot of trouble if you need to update the version of AlloyUI you're using, since dependencies may change. The module loading is one of the advantages of using AlloyUI, so I'd recommend not using it without it.